# dynamic_cast (int* to int *) - compilation error

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

For the following code:

```
int i = 8;

int * p_i = &i;
int * p_j;

if (typeid(p_i) != typeid(p_j))
{
     p_j= dynamic_cast<int *>(p_i);
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

> error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘p_i’ (of type ‘int*’) to type ‘int*’ (target is not pointer or reference to class)

What am I missing?

P.S. It is a simplified example of a behaviour that I get (with template functions etc.), so don't try to find any purpose in this code segment.

UPD:
As this code is a part of a template function, I can't know if I get a complete class or a primitive - this is the reason.

Comment: [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) is for polymorphism with classes. Not using pointers to native types like `int`. If you have two variables of the same type, why use a cast in the first place?

Comment: Why use `dynamic_cast` if you already have an `if` on `typeid`? Unless you want the cast to traverse the inheritance hierarchy, it is not needed.

Comment: Because I have a template function that can have both primitive and polymorhyc type

Comment: How about using [type-traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_traits_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29) to handle the different cases of primitive types and classes?

Comment: I cannot use currently C++ 11 - only C++98.

Comment: @EricAbramov [Use boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler error points out, you cannot use `dynamic_cast` to cast to `int*`.

Use `reinterpret_cast` for that.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **5.2.7 Dynamic cast** [expr.dynamic.cast]
>
> 1 The result of the expression `dynamic_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. `T` shall be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or “pointer to *cv* void.”